# C#.NET MongoDriver error MongoCommandException

Tags: c#, mongodb

Just starting using MongoDB. However I'm getting error below which makes no sense to me (coming from SQL Server). Could you please help me understand what is causing this issue?

```
30440 2015:12:15 05:09:19 ERROR Application error.
Exception: MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException
Message: Command 'update' failed: not master (response: { "note" : "from execCommand", "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "not master" })
Source: MongoDB.Driver
   at MongoDB.Driver.Operations.CommandOperation`1.Execute(MongoConnection connection)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Operations.BulkUnmixedWriteOperationBase.ExecuteBatch(MongoConnection connection, Batch`1 batch, Int32 originalIndex)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Operations.BulkUnmixedWriteOperationBase.Execute(MongoConnection connection)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Operations.BulkUpdateOperation.Execute(MongoConnection connection)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Operations.UpdateOpcodeOperationEmulator.Execute(MongoConnection connection)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Operations.UpdateOpcodeOperation.Execute(MongoConnection connection)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.Update(IMongoQuery query, IMongoUpdate update, MongoUpdateOptions options)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.Update(IMongoQuery query, IMongoUpdate update, UpdateFlags flags, WriteConcern writeConcern)
   at Sitecore.SessionProvider.MongoDB.MongoSessionStateStore.InsertItem(String application, String id, Int32 flags, SessionStateStoreData sessionState)
   at Sitecore.SessionProvider.MongoDB.SimpleMongoSessionStateStore.InsertItem(String application, String id, Int32 flags, SessionStateStoreData sessionState)
   at Sitecore.SessionProvider.MongoDB.MongoSessionStateProvider.SetAndReleaseItemExclusive(HttpContext context, String id, SessionStateStoreData sessionState, Object lockId, Boolean newItem)
   at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.OnReleaseState(Object source, EventArgs eventArgs)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: Can you provide code?

Comment: Unfortunately it's a sitecore internal mongo provider.